# AppleScript throwing error on hdiutil command

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mountain-lion, hdiutil

I have the following code in an AppleScript file, which should mount a sparsebundle hosted on my network.  Running this script throws an error on the **hdiutil** command:

```
try
  mount volume "smb://192.168.1.1/sda2"
end try

do shell script "hdiutil attach -mountpoint /Volumes/sda2 timemachine.sparsebundle"
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
hdiutil: attach failed - No such file or directory" number 1
```

Running the shell script code in Terminal works just fine, and the script builds fine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working.  I changed the `hdiutil` command syntax and now AppleScript does not throw an error.

```
try
  mount volume "smb://192.168.1.1/sda2"
end try

do shell script "hdiutil attach /Volumes/sda2/timemachine.sparsebundle/"
```

Not sure why the original command still works in Terminal but fails in AppleScript, but at least it works now.